# No charts option in JasperServer Adhoc report from OLAP Connection?

Tags: jasper-reports, olap, jasperserver, olap-cube

I have made a OLAP cube using Jasper OLAP designer. Than I have made a OLAP connection using that OLAP schema in Jasper Server.

My aim is to generate report using that OLAP cube. Basically the scheduled report in PDF format having tabular as well as Chart in it.

Now when I select Create->Ad Hoc report -> OLAP connection.. I don't get the option of charts. Only option there is Crosstab. From this I am able to get tabular report only.

I don't know what wrong.. My concern is how to make this report with charts.. My question may be wrong.. I am new in Jasper, OLAP and all. Kindly give me some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reports in iReport that use an OLAP data source. These can include charts (or anything else supported by JasperReports).

But in Ad Hoc when you choose an OLAP source, you can only create crosstab reports. That limitation will go away in the next release... but for now you can't create charts there.

Comment: Can you give some tutorial link of making report using OLAP data source from iReports.... I used iReport earlier also.. but I worked only with JDBC connections... This time I have made OLAP cube using Jasper OLAP designer.. Is that possible in iReport to make reports over that cube.. ???

Comment: and also one more question.. may be somewhat off the topic.. but how OLAP cube that what I made from OLAP workbench and Domains creating in JasperServer are relation.. if there is any relation.. I asked this question because I can see there is a option of charts when we make reports from domain...

Comment: Yes, it seems like a different topic. Please post a new question.